# how to change Magento homepage title quickly of website

Tags: magento2, title

how to change Magento homepage title quickly of  website, that help you optimize your Magento site for search engines.

Answer (score 1):

```
Admin > Content > Pages > Homepage > Page Title > Save
```

You can also set the default website Title in :

```
Admin > Content > Configuration > Your Website > Edit > HTML head > Title and Meta description
```